# Sudoku não imprime respostas na tela

Tags: c

Este código não tem nenhum erro, porém o programa não resolve o jogo (não imprime as respostas na tela):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 9
#define D 4

void facil(void);
void medio(void);
void dificil(void);
int isValueInLineOrColumn(int val, int arr[N][N], int line, int column);
int isValueInLineOrColum(int val, int arr[D][D], int line, int column);

int conferencia;

int main()
{
    int opc=0;

    printf("1-facil\t2-medio\t3-dificil");
    scanf("%d", &opc);

    conferencia=opc;

    switch(opc)/*para a função do nivel escolhido*/
    {
        case 1:
            facil();
            break;

        case 2:
            medio();
        break;

        case 3:
            dificil();
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void facil(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    int mesa[D][D];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("facil.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                printf( "%c", mesa[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    arquivo=fopen("facil.txt","a");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            int val = 1+rand()%N;

            while((mesa[i][j]=0))
            {
                if(isValueInLineOrColum(val, mesa, i, j))
                    mesa[i][j]=0;
                else
                    mesa[i][j]=val;
            }   
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}

void medio(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    int mesa[N][N];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("medio.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
            {
                   fflush(stdin);
                    printf( "%c", mesa[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    arquivo=fopen("medio.txt","a");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            int val = 1+rand()%N;

            while((mesa[i][j]=0))
            {
                if(isValueInLineOrColumn(val, mesa, i, j))
                    mesa[i][j]=0;
                else
                    mesa[i][j]=val;
            }   
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}

void dificil(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    int mesa[N][N];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("dificil.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf( "%c", mesa[i][j]);
                }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    arquivo=fopen("dificil.txt","a");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            int val = 1+rand()%N;

            while((mesa[i][j]=0))
            {
                if(isValueInLineOrColumn(val, mesa, i, j))
                    mesa[i][j]=0;
                else
                    mesa[i][j]=val;
            }   
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}

int isValueInLineOrColumn(int val, int arr[N][N], int line, int column)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[line][i] == val)
            return 1;

        if (arr[i][column] == val)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int isValueInLineOrColum(int val, int arr[D][D], int line, int column)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[line][i] == val)
            return 1;

        if (arr[i][column] == val)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Baixo a postagem original

Eu tenho esse sudoku aqui e preciso fazer com que o PC jogue sozinho.
Eu fiz as regras mas não consigo fazer um meio de imprimir isso e salvar no arquivo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 9

void facil(void);
void medio(void);
void dificil(void);
void play(void);
int isValueInLineOrColumn(int val, int arr[N][N], int line, int column);

int conferencia;

int main()
{
    int opc=0;

    printf("1-facil\t2-medio\t3-dificil");
    scanf("%d", &opc);

    conferencia=opc;

    switch(opc)/*para a função do nivel escolhido*/
    {
        case 1:
            facil();
            break;

        case 2:
            medio();
        break;

        case 3:
            dificil();
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void facil(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    char mesa[4][4];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("facil.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("%c", mesa[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void medio(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    char mesa[N][N];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("medio.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
            {
                   fflush(stdin);
                    printf("%c", mesa[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void dificil(void)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    char mesa[N][N];
    int i, j;

    arquivo=fopen("dificil.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            while((mesa[i][j]=fgetc(arquivo))!=EOF)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("%c", mesa[i][j]);
                }
        }
    }
}

int isValueInLineOrColumn(int val, int arr[N][N], int line, int column)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[line][i] == val)
            return 1;

        if (arr[i][column] == val)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tem que seguir em arquivo.

Comment: Não te esqueças que nem todos as gerações aleatórias de números dão algum resultado

Comment: Existem mais regras do sudoku... Era melhor leres

Answer (score 2):

Estás a ler mal do ficheiro, e a escrever também. Porque estás a ler as `|` e as `-`. Estás a perceber?

O teu arquivo tem de ter somente os números para leres e escreveres, tipo:

arquivo fácil

```
0240
1003
4002
0130
```

Claro que também podes ler como os arquivos estão atualmente, mas dá mais um bocadinho de trabalho.

Fiz também uma melhoria no código: http://ideone.com/F7JHXU

Comment: esse tipo de erro é o meu pior sou dislexo mas estou treinando isso. vou testar aqui

Comment: então Joge B. ele ainda nao resolve o sudoku não há motivos para imprimir no arquivo as respostas tb vou mudar prara `r` na abertura do arquivo

Comment: `bash: line 1:      229 segmentation fault       (core dumped)  ./program` o seu deu isso ai e nao mostrou nada, nao sei o que é, mas errors e warnings nao tinha

Comment: Devo me ter esquecido de alguma coisa, depois confirmo

Comment: ok entao, sem problemas eu estou preso no programa pq fiz a correções no meu codigo e agora nao tem erro e ele so imprime o q tem dentro do txt e nao resolve o jgo =/

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin onde está a parte que resolve o jogo?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o seu código está "quase lá". Use `fprintf` para escrever em um arquivo. Ele funciona da mesma forma que o `printf`, mas tem um parâmetro a mais que é o arquivo. Lembre-se de usar `fclose` para fechar os arquivos abertos.

Comment: ok comentarei mais apos chegar em casa obrigado